# Regarding connect with vb.net to ibm mq 9.1

Tags: ibm-mq

Actually my application is migrating  from vb to vb.net. So can anyone help that what are the steps to connect vb.net to IBM MQ 9.1 .

Comment: There are samples shipped with product, for example tools\dotnet\samples\vb\vmqsput.vb

Comment: You'll need to give some more details. What have you done so far? How is it failing? Show us the connection code. Tell us if this is client/local bindings, and if client, how you are providing connection details? Is the managed, or non-managed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi guys ,As iam new to ibmmq so can anyone help how to setup ibm mq 9.1 in between two application from scratch level  means ( How to configure, how to install in server, etc..)

Note: My both application are vb.net